# Is there a term for "because the script needed it" for things that otherwise don't make sense?

Tags: literary-device

And yes I know of a MacGuffin, but I'm thinking more of other plot tools.

**Edit** and it's not Deus Ex Machina. It's not some random outside event.  It's people making odd choices that further along a predestined plot.

Why was the secret chip in a car in Fast Five/Furious 7?  Because the script needed it. Why did they go up against a tank in a 70s Japanese car?  Because the script needed it. Why did the (now widowed) woman of the man James Bond killed suddenly want to bang his killer in Spectre?  Because the script needed it. Why did Batman fight Superman? Didn't make sense, but the ....  You get it.

**Edit** I did hear one phrase, though limited (obviously) to visual media - F--k the plot, just set up the shot

Comment: Are you looking for a single word? Or a replacement phrase?

Comment: @TimMalone Either. Both. :). Single word is preferred for conciseness but common usage good too

Comment: It should be noted that any story (or at least any interesting one) has plot twists that hinge on an event, decision, or object that was (presumably) present from the start (or whose appearance was reasonably possible from the start) but whose significance was unapparent until later.  This can be subtle and "seamless", or it can be hokey -- it all depends on the skill of the author.

Comment: I would call the whole process "writing oneself into and out of a corner."

Comment: Setting aside your first example, which is an example of a  plot device, you're talking about actions of characters within stories that have no justification other than to advance the story.  In a well constructed story I don't think that occurs so I think you're talking about weak writing.  But it's not necessarily unenjoyable.  Robert Howard, the creator of Conan, said his plotting was simple.  He put Conan into an impossible situation and gave him a sword to hack his way out.

Answer (score 3):

An oldie but goodie is [deus ex machina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina), literally "god from the machine", though

> The term has evolved to mean a plot device whereby a seemingly unsolvable problem is suddenly and abruptly resolved by the inspired and unexpected intervention of some new event, character, ability or object.

The term applies literally to theater, in some cases, when, eg, an angel drops out of the "fly space" to rescue the hero.  (It's much more common to use the term in the figurative sense, of course.)

Comment: I thought of that, but that's not it. It's not as if some meteor hit the GT40 and embedded a chip in it. Someone had the (odd) choice to put a chip on a 60s race car, because..... Umm.... LeMans?

Answer (score 2):

A [MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) (or McGuffin) can be considered a narrative conceit that exists purely to further the plot.

Comment: But it's an object. What about other cases when people act odd?  In the Sex and the City movie (yes I'm a good husband) Carrie went crazy on wedding dresses when in the show she literally got a rash from a wedding dress. Why? Script needed it. Made drama for the wedding. No McGuffin.

Comment: A McGuffin does not have to be a physical object. Even an intangible, inexplicable emotional outburst can be considered a McGuffin if the immediate plot revolves around its resolution. To quote Hitchcock, it is "a plot device that motivates the characters and advances the story."

Comment: True, but still not the crux of my issue.  For me it's not "people are after object X" but "people do A and B, even though that doesn't make sense to them, because they need Z to happen at the end"

Comment: It might break the fourth wall, but it would seem "people are acting out-of-character because the writer's hand is guiding them to Z".

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions that I hope you might find interesting if not completely accurate: ontological; circular-logic; self-referential; self-serving; chicken and egg; ouroboros; chasing its own tale; the opposite of self-defeating; plot-essential.

Answer (score -2):

There is a very succinct way of expressing this.
When there appears to be no explanation, or a proferred explanation makes no sense, one says "Because ....":
Why are so many people losing their medical insurance? Because Obamacare.
Why are we bombing the Middle East to smithereens? Because democracy.
Why are so many of my friends jobless? Because recovery.

Sometimes we think it's too much trouble, or we have never thought the matter out ourselves, so when asked for an explanation, we say "Because.", or "Just because." or "Because I say so." This works best with children: when it stops working, you know your child is growing up.

But in literature, it's usually a sign of one of three things: A poorly-constructed plot; a lazy writer, who comes across a problem that should have been thought of earlier; or multiple writers who don't read each other's scripts very attentively.